# Website direct folder access by URL

Tags: ssh, firefox, permissions

I have a trival web site which consists of index.html, that page's images, and several subfolders.  I want to share folder access with friends and family via a URL similar to:  https://mydomain/folder

This used to work on a different host as http only.  My site is now hosted on gandi.net without Wordpress or any such site builder.  Any URL which directly accesses a folder gets "Forbidden", etc.  SSH shows folder permissions are 755, and file permissions are 644, so I do not believe the problem lies there.

There is a .htaccess file, but all it does is redirect www.domain to domain.  If the solution involves .htaccess, I will need specific help.  I'm an old-time computer guy, but web sites are outside my experience.

Post-Solutiion edit:  .htaccess command vocabulary is large and complex.  Here is the specfic content I put in each folder to make it work,  Comments follow.

```
Options +Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|mp4|mov|MOV|7z|zip|iso)$">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
</RequireAll>
```

The Options command opened access, but the files would open in the web browser.  The "FilesMatch" block forces files with the specified extensions to be downloaded to the visitor's device.  I don't know whether the "RequireAll" block does any good.  It was something I had tried earlier.

Comment: Are you expecting to get a list of files in that folder? Do you know what webserver software gandi.net uses; do they give you any control over its configuration?

Comment: I have no idea what gandi.net uses, and I have no control above the htdocs level, where index.html is.  Yes, I expect the visitor to see a list of files and to be able to download any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: OP explains that the real

> solution was to add "Options +Indexes" to the .htaccess file in each folder and at the site root level

since it turns out that gandi's origin server is [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#file-and-web).

## static solution

You are able to create new .html files,
therefore you are definitely able to make this work:

```
$ PREAMBLE='BEGIN {print "<!DOCTYPE html><title>hello</title><body>"}  '
$ ls -l |
    awk $PREAMBLE'{print $0"<br>"}' |
    tidy -iq  > index.html
```

In a browser navigate to ...name/of/folder/index.html,
or even to just ...name/of/folder.

Downside is you would need to remember to re-run the script
whenever the directory contents change.

(To keep it simple I am not generating `href`s -- I leave that
as an exercise to the reader.)

## dynamic solution

First, what web server is involved here?
Let's ask gandi.net.

```
$ curl -i https://www.gandi.net/en
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx
...
```

Good, now we know which body of documentation to consult.

I sure hope gandi has `ngx_http_autoindex_module` enabled.

In the `nginx.conf` config file we want something like this:

```
location /name/of/folder/ {
    autoindex on;
}
```

Try adjusting your `.htaccess` file so it turns auto indexing on.
If your edits have no effect, then you will have to chat with
a gandi admin to find if the module is enabled and what changes
you should make. At least [one](https://docs.gandi.net/en/simple_hosting/advanced_configurations/php_settings.html) of their docs suggests
that they anticipate the module should be enabled, though
that document describes a setup different from yours,
using Apache rather than Nginx.
(EDIT: My guess there was incorrect --
turns out it's Apache that is reading your .html files.)

Comment: Thorough answer for a variety of cases.  Thank you very much!  Specific solution was to add "Options +Indexes" to the .htaccess file in each folder and at the site root level.